# How to use an open source TypeScript library from my ASP.NET Core project's .ts file?

Tags: node.js, typescript, asp.net-core, npm

**Context**

- I've successfully created new ASP.NET Core Web App using VS 2019.
- Also successfully added typescript support by adding NuGet
  `Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild` `Version="4.4.2"`
- I've added a
  mydemo.ts to the /scripts folder configured tsconfig.json, everything
  **is working fine.**

Now I would like to use an open source js library in my project from typescript. **The js library is written in typescript**, and the readme page on github says `npm install thelibrary` (btw the next line in the getting started is `import * as <thetype> from 'thelibrary'`

OK, so I've added npm support to my project via packages.json, and Visual Studio successfully downloaded the package, which created multiple folders below the /node_modules.

Under the downloaded /node_modules/thelibrary/build subfolder there is a single .js and .map file, but no single .d.ts file. Instead there is an esm subfolder with many subfolders and many .js and .map and .d.ts files.

So I thought I can use the topmost index.d.ts.

**Question**

From here I completely lost. I do not want to build "thelibrary" from scratch, I only want to use it as black box library. I do not even know, how the single .js and .map files supposed to copied to the wwwroot, but that is   a minor problem.

The biggest problem, if I try to `/// <reference path=` to the topmost index.d.ts that seems to be compile, however my own lines what try to use some of referenced type in gives a "Can not find name: " error. VS tryes to add an import statement for this error, which is a compile error.

Is it possible that the only way to use this library from a .ts file is include the full .ts code of the library (as generated .d.ts file does not exist)?

I am very basic level in typescript, and regarding .js module systems the only thing I know: they exist... seems to be hopeless either ask either answer... anyway I attach some config file and picture... The js library btw is [tonejs, see here in github](https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js), but I am convinced *my question is not specific to that library*.

tsconfig.js:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "ES2015",
    //"moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "wwwroot/js"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ],
  "include": [
    "scripts/**/*"
  ]
}
```

packages.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "tone": "14.7.39"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try importing by file path? For example: `import File from "./../../../../node_modules/vinyl"`

Comment: Yes, I've tried. It raises a `Cannot find module ./../node_modules/tone'. Did you mean to set the 'moduleResolution' option to 'node', or to add aliases to the 'paths' option?` error message. If I set 'moduleResolution', then it raises zilloin of errors...